# Exception with react-native to apk

Tags: react-native, eas

I have got exception fron eas build -p android

```
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/android
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-permission/android/build.gradle' line: 14
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-permission'.
[stderr] > Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s
```

Please, help, yarn add react-native-peremission doesn't help